# How to arrange views in cell when one views height is changed?

Tags: ios, swift

in my project I am adding views in a stack view programatically. What I need here is, whenever a new view is added, increase the size of the stack view. And according to the new height of stack view, move other items bellow to avoid intersection of all views.

However, this is what happens: http://imgur.com/a/BnPvl

The view and unlike buttons are supposed to be bellow stack view. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width, 100))
        let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, cell.frame.width, 100))
        let label3 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, cell.frame.width, 100))
        label.text = "Label"
        label2.text = "I am a test content."
        label3.text = "I am a longer test content but not that long, just enough to make 2 lines maybe"
        cell.mystack.addSubview(label)
        cell.mystack.addSubview(label2)
        cell.mystack.addSubview(label3)
        cell.mystack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.mystack.frame.width, 300)
```

Comment: Where do you create view and unlike buttons? By programmatically or in IB? if its in IB (which i can't see them, are they in "Action"), did you set the view and unlike button's top constraints? if they are created by programmatically, did you set their frame according to new stack frame? And add try layoutIfNeeded after you set all frames.

Comment: Buttons are are dynamically created in a UICollectionView bellow the stackview (There is a cell named Actions). Where do I add layoutIfNeeded? To collectionView or stackview?

Comment: I didnt realize it's a collectionView, I thought it's a tableView. Okay then. You need to change cell size dynamically too. In collectionView's sizeForItemAtIndexPath method, you need to set cell's size is equal (or bigger) to mystack frame size.